# How to assign value to html body variable in Jscript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing the MVC application with razor syntax.
I have declare one variable at the begining of the code 'DeductedAmount'

```
@model PaymentAdviceEntity.PaymentAdvice
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Custom1.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  @{
  double DeductedAmount;         
}
```

Now I want to assign some value in Javasacript. 
How to do that ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('@DeductedAmount') = '@Model.SanctionedAmount' - '@Model.DeductionAmount'
});
```

but its not working...
How to do this ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You are creating 3 doubles as server-side variables and then using the value of one of them as a jquery selector, which won't work

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do this?:

```
@{
    double DeductedAmount = Model.SanctionedAmount - Model.DeductionAmount;         
}
```

Comment: Its giving error , Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Looks like the properties in your model are nullable. You should test their HasValue property before doing the calculation and handle the condition when they're null appropriately. Then change your code to be double DeductedAmount = Model.SanctionedAmount.Value - Model.DeductionAmount.Value